# Why is my discord.py bot not deploying from GitHub to AWS EC2 via CodeDeploy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, server, discord.py

I'm completely new to hosting web projects on the internet, and after trying SparkedHost (wouldn't let me use selenium) and Heroku (wouldn't let me save screenshot files for some reason) I got some advice to try out EC2. I have a fully functional discord.py bot (that leans on selenium pretty heavily might I add) that runs just fine on my laptop, but I cannot get it to deploy to EC2.

I have:

- An EC2 instance that I have been able to connect to via EC2 Instance Connect, and I've installed all the python libraries that I need (including discord)
- A CodeDeploy application (called `codedeploy`)
- A Deployment group called `githubdeploy` that is connected to a service role I created and connected to my instance

I have tried deploying this six different times, each time fixing something I thought was incorrect, but nothing. I keep getting the `ERROR [codedeploy-agent(7326)]: InstanceAgent::Plugins::CodeDeployPlugin::CommandPoller: Missing credentials - please check if this instance was started with an IAM instance profile` when I run `tail -f /var/log/aws/codedeploy-agent/codedeploy-agent.log` in my EC2 Instance Connect.